# How does Internet Explorer 8 determine a site to be "local intranet?"

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

How does Internet Explorer 8 determine a site to be a "local intranet" site? I'm trying to workaround the fact that IE8 renders one of my projects in **compatibility view** and breaks one item in particular, (CSS3 PIE's rounded corners.)

I'm wondering if there's a way to trick IE into thinking the site is not an intranet site without changing settings in the browser. Is this a possibility?

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to avoid your document rendering in IE7 mode, you should add to your HEAD the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />` tag.

Comment: Apologies, I meant to say compatibility mode. I fixed document mode already.